# How to tell /bin/bash the correct php version? (Mavericks)

Tags: php, bash, shell, osx-mavericks

I am using SublimeText to run PHPUnit tests continuosly. Works great, but now I stumbled upon something strange. I updated to the latest PHP version via Homebrew and if I open a Terminal session and type `php -v`, this is what I get:

```
PHP 5.6.7 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2015 19:03:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

The shell instance that is used by SublimeText seems not to use this version of PHP. If I do the same there (via writing `echo shell_exec('php -v');die();` into a PHPUnit test), I get this:

```
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I tested around a bit and found out, that automator puts out the same if I run a shell script in \bin\bash shell via automator's 'run shell script' action.

How to tell /bin/bash to use the newly installed PHP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue the command `$ php`, the `PATH` is searched for the binary. You can find out which one will be executed with the command `$ which php`.

If you want to explicitly run one or another php binary when multiple ones are installed, use full absolute path to the binary, e.g. `$ /opt/php5.6/bin/php`.

Comment: I get that. I can run `/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php -v` and get the correct information. But how to tell \bin\bash to use this by default?

Comment: By identifying the command with full absolute path. Or, just make sure the version you do not want to run is not in your PATH while the other is.

Comment: Okay, tried this out. Problem is, I can't. PHPUnit is run via `vendor\bin\phpunit` and I can't set the php path. When it comes to removing the default php binary from PATH, I'm kind of a noob. How to do this?

Comment: The problem is that a default PHP installation will place the binary or a symlink to it in `/usr/bin` which you don't want to remove from the `PATH` variable. (Check you path by `$ echo $PATH`, set it in the `~/.bashrc` file.) Your situation is special so it requires special actions - you need to remove distro default PHP installation and reinstall it to non default location or install PHP versions manually.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just give up. There are better ways to do continuos unit tests... ;-)